# Construction of Free modules in a monoidal category

Tags: modules, monoid, monoidal-categories

Let $(C,\otimes , 1^C , \alpha , \lambda , \rho)$ be a monoidal category and let $\mathsf{Mon}_C$ be the category of monoids in $C$. And let $A \in \mathsf{Mon}_C$. Denote the category of $A$-modules by $A-\mathsf{Mod}_C$. Under what conditions does the forgetful functor $U : A-\mathsf{Mod}_C \to C$ have a left adjoint?

I am used to the free $R$-module on a set $S$. But this is different than the above situation because the explicit construction in this case makes reference to properties I do not know the categorical analogue. I have seen the definition of the free $R$-module as $R^{(S)}$, which is all finitely supported set function from $S$ to the underlying set of $R$. I am able to show that this is indeed the free $R$-module on $S$. But this does not generalize since it requires that $R$ have underlying set. It also requires a notion of finitely supported.

My idea to generalize this to a arbitrary monoidal category with monoid $A$ in $C$ is the following: for an object $c \in C$, we want the  to speak of some sort of "coproduct of $A$ indexed by c". But I'm not sure how to go about making this precise. Any ideas I have on this require importing lots of extra structure into $C$.

My main question is under what conditions doeu $U$ admit a left adjoint? I am also interested in a construction of this adjoint, in cases where it exists. References are also appreciated.

Comment: The free module on a set is really not analogous, since a ring is not a monoid object in the category of sets.

Comment: The familiar analogue of this occurs when you take the monoidal category to be, say, $k$-vector spaces, and $A$ to be a $k$-algebra. Then you are asking for the free $A$-module on a $k$-vector space, or the left adjoint to restriction of scalars from $A$-modules to $k$-modules, which is extension of scalars $A \otimes_k (-)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forgetful functor $U$ always has a left adjoint, which is given by just $F(X)=A\otimes X$.  For any object $X$ of $C$, the object $A\otimes X$ has a canonical $A$-module structure, given by the composition $A\otimes (A\otimes X)\to (A\otimes A)\otimes X\to A\otimes X$ where the first map is the associator and the second is the multiplication of $A$.  There is also a canonical $C$-morphism $X\to A\otimes X$ given by the composition $X\to 1\otimes X\to A\otimes X$ where the first map is the unitor and the second is the unit of $A$.  This in fact makes $A\otimes X$ the free $A$-module on $X$: if $M$ is any other $A$-module with a $C$-morphism $f:X\to M$, this induces a map $A\otimes X\to M$ given by composing $A\otimes f:A\otimes X\to A\otimes M$ with the module structure map $A\otimes M\to M$.  This composition is an $A$-module morphism (by associativity of the module structure on $M$).  Moreover, it is the unique $A$-module morphism which factors $f$ through the canonical map $X\to A\otimes X$ (if you apply the functor $A\otimes -$ to that commutative diagram it forces the map $A\otimes X\to M$ to be defined as above by unitality of the $A$-module structure of $M$).

Comment: Thank you. That helps quite a bit. Do you know if the construction of a free monoid on an object of $C$ is quite as easy?

Comment: That is much harder, and will not exist in general.  (I don't know off the top of my head when it will exist, but you definitely need some colimits to exist, and maybe for $\otimes$ to preserve them.)

Comment: thanks! That makes sense.